# Load Laravel eloquent attribute by string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am storing some strings in my database, and I want to be able to get model attributes using them.

Basically, I can call a users booking like this

```
$user->bookings->date
```

in my controller and it works, and i'm storing a string in my database like this

```
'user->bookings->date'
```

How can I use this string from the database to get the attribute? I'm hoping to be able to do something like

```
$user = User::findOrFail(1);
$string = 'user->bookings->date'; //This is fetched from the db normally
$booking_date = ${$string}; //Instead of writing $user->bookings->date
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Won't exactly work like that, as the object accessor `->` needs to be outside of `{}` to work properly. i.e. something like `${$string1}->{$string2}->{$string3};` would work, but I'm not sure how to construct that dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution that involves chaining object access from a static string:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(1);

$string = "user->bookings->date";
$params = explode("->", $string);

$var = null;
foreach($params AS $param){
    if($var){
        $var = $var->{$param};
    } else {
        $var = ${$param};
    }
}

dd($var);
```

On the first iteration of `$params`, set `$var` to the value of `${$param}` (`$user`). Then, on the next iterations, set `$var` to the value of `$var->{$param}` (`$user->bookings`, `$user->bookings->date`). Then, finally, echo out (or `dd()`) the value of `$var`. In my test, this results in

```
"2019-06-18 12:06:00"
```

So while it requires a bit of additional logic, it is possible to set object access from a database string.

Comment: This looks good, I've managed to find a method using the `eval` function, but every fibre of my being screams at me to not use it, just incase.

Comment: Yeah... `eval()` can be great when you know you will have absolute control of what's being evaluated, but performing it on something that can change a lot is a terrible idea :P

Comment: Yup, i'm not going to allow my users to type in a string, the string that is stored will be built dynamically, to avoid anyone simply typing `$user->delete()` or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arr::get`
helper
[method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-array-get)

With this, you can use "dot notation". So you should change the '->' with '.'
and the 'user.' with ''

```
$string = "user->bookings->date";
$field = str_replace("->", ".", $string);
$field = str_replace("user.", "", $field);
// We want the string "bookings.date"

$user = User::findOrFail(1);

Arr::get($user, $field, "default value")
```

With this, you can go deeper as you need, and this returns you a single column or a collection if you have `hasMany` relation